# File created in linux transferred to Windows shows corrupted

Tags: linux, excel, windows

I have created an Excel file from delimted text file using awk in linux terminal transferring the same to windows. when opened it shows a pop-up "This file might be corrupted or unsafe.would you like to open?"But on tapping yes I could see data everything is fine as expected.How to avoid such pop-up.
I have tried to convert to .xlsx then I couldn't even see the data
I tried to zip and send then unzip same warning popsup

Comment: Pehaps just saving it again under Windows would fix this problem.  Do you plan to move files between Linux and Windows often?

Comment: Only once I will do transfer and data is just for seeing the status of things we will open it only once.But the process runs every month i.e,one file for every month end.

Comment: "I have created an Excel file from delimited text file using awk in linux terminal." How exactly? I suspect you have created a `CSV` file and simply named it `*.xls`. This is not really a Excel file and thus Excel warns about the mismatch between file extension and file content while opening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess as to what is going on is that the incoming Excel file is still basically a Linux file, but MS Office, being flexible, is allowing you to open it.  For a one time fix, try the following steps from Windows Excel:

- Open the Linux Excel file (`some_file.xlsx`)
- Save as another file name (`some_new_file.xlsx`)
- Close Excel
- Delete `some_file.xlsx` and rename `some_new_file.xlsx` to `some_file.xlsx`

Now try opening the file again, and hopefully the error message will have gone away.